# Concatenating a declared but not defined variable

Tags: javascript, concatenation

Out of curiosity I did this simple concatenation:

```
let a;
a+="hello"
console.log(a)
```

It returns `"undefinedhello"`

I get that **a** was basically the string "undefined", or is it converted to a string when concatenating? Is there something to learn here?

Comment: "is it converted to a string when concatenating" - yes.

Comment: To elaborate, the default initial value for variables is `undefined`, therefore, `let a;` and `let a = undefined;` are equivalent. When in an addition one side is a string, the other gets converted to string implicitly. The string conversion `String(undefined)` gives `'undefined'`, and string-concatenation then gives your result.

Comment: javascript is not strongly typed and does a lot of possibly unintuitively things for you. this is one of those things

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a="";
a+="hello"
console.log(a)
```

since you are creating a variable here so the default value becomes **undefined** . You need to assign a value over there.

[check here](https://flexiple.com/undefined-vs-null-javascript/)

Comment: You could do this without defining an initial value for `a` using [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#short-circuit_evaluation): `a=(a||'')+b`.